# Update the chart data from an array stored in a variable on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I have a chart that gets the data values from a table column. It currently works on its own, but I want to add a functionality that changes/updates the data of the chart on button click. I tried this code but it doesn't work (arrays are very confusing for me):

```js
var canvasP = document.getElementById("pieChart");
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var nameArr = [];
var data1Arr = [];
var data2Arr = [];
var tableLen = table.rows.length;
var i;

for (i = 1; i < tableLen; i++) {
  nameArr.push(table.rows[i].cells[0].textContent);
  data1Arr.push(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
  data2Arr.push(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
}

nameArr.pop();
data1Arr.pop();
data2Arr.pop();

var ctxP = canvasP.getContext("2d");

var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    labels: nameArr,
    datasets: [{
      data: data1Arr,
      backgroundColor: ["#64B5F6", "#FFD54F", "#2196F3", "#FFC107", "#1976D2", "#FFA000", "#0D47A1", "#64B5F6", "#FFD54F", "#2196F3", "#FFC107", "#1976D2", "#FFA000", "#0D47A1"],
      label: "Data"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "right"
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Data 1"
    }
  }
});

// the button functions below do not work. I am trying to load the array variables into the data:

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  myPieChart.data.datasets.data = data1Arr;
});

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  myPieChart.data.datasets.data = data2Arr;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>1st data</th>
      <th>2nd data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</th>
      <td>337</td>
      <td>411</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 2</th>
      <td>290</td>
      <td>110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 3</th>
      <td>197</td>
      <td>800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 4</th>
      <td>765</td>
      <td>211</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 5</th>
      <td>331</td>
      <td>451</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 6</th>
      <td>957</td>
      <td>871</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <td id='curPop'>2877</td>
      <td>2854</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<canvas id='pieChart'></canvas>

<button id="btn1">
Data 1
</button>
<button id="btn2">
Data 2
</button>
```

What I would want is that when the `Data 2` button is clicked, it loads the appropriate data from the table (**2nd data**) into the pie chart, and that the `Data 1` button loads the **1st data** of the table.

Answer (score 2):

After testing several times, this seems to fix the issue:

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click",function(){
myPieChart.data.datasets[0].data = data1Arr;
myPieChart.update();
});

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click",function(){
myPieChart.data.datasets[0].data = data2Arr;
myPieChart.update();
});
```